# Why does my Lenovo T410 freezes at about 80% through the iis installation process?

Tags: thinkpad, iis-7

I've been unable to install IIS on my Lenovo T410 Windows 7 machine for days now. I check all of the IIS components, as i've always done on my other computers running Windows 7, and the install never completes. The process freezes my computer, which i have to forcefully power-down in other to restart.

I have gone through the files and immediate sub-directories %windir% and %windir%/system32, but i've been unable to find a log with a name like iis.txt.

The system in question here, was just restored to factory settings using the "Blue Button - ThinkVantage".

I suspect it might be some program or service causing the problem. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What version of IIS are you trying to install? Have you installed ALL updates offered?  If you suspect a program, then remove all installed programs, and keep trying to install IIS until you eliminate that possability.